# How to join rows of a matrix?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to merge all the cells on the rows of a matrix, in order to get a vector with the components derived from the joined rows. The original matrix is the result of a more complex `ARRAYFORMULA`.

I already tried with `CONCATENATE` but what I obtain is a unique cell, instead of a vector.

For example, I have a 3x3 matrix:

```
A   B   C
D   E   F
G   H   I
```

I would like to obtain a vector like so:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

Comment: what do you mean by "a vector"?

Comment: An ARRAY, sorry. (in Italian the translation of array and vector is the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 SUBSTITUTE(A1:C, " ", "♦")), , 999^99))), " ", ""), "♦", " "))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This is a really neat approach +1 (in fact I can't think of another way of doing it without 50K restriction) but I couldn't understand the purpose of all the substitutes e.g. this seemed to work =ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 A1:C), , 999^99))," ",""))

Comment: @TomSharpe those extra substitutes are kinda "safety precautions for future possible states" - in case A1 would be `A A` and as the task is to concentrate columns only not also individual values

Comment: OK, got it (could have shown an example I guess) but good point.